# UserSearcher/UserPrinciple: Users have been deleted already

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices

I am trying to use PrincipalSearcher to search for any users with a specific DisplayName and delete them.

If there are no users with a matching DisplayName, the code operates fine. If one is found though, an exception is raised stating:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't delete an already deleted
>   object
>          at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.CheckDisposedOrDeleted()
>          at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.get_Name()}

I have placed a breakpint on user.delete() and can confirm that there is a user present. As soon as the Delete call is made though, the exception is raised.

I can't see where the object has been deleted. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public string DeleteUsers()
{
    using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
        ContextType.Machine, null
        ))
    {
        using (var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext))
        {
            // All users will have the same DisplayName
            userPrincipal.DisplayName = UserDisplayName;

            //
            // Search for all users with the above displayName
            //
            using (var principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(
                userPrincipal
                ))
            {
                var users = principalSearcher.FindAll();
                string userString = "";

                // Loop through each of them and delete them
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    var username = user.Name;

                    try
                    {
                        user.Delete();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return $"Error: Could not delete user: {username}. " +
                            $"{e.Message}";
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userString))
                    {
                        userString += ", ";
                    }
                    userString += username;

                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userString))
                {
                    return "No users deleted.";
                }

                return "Deleted the following users: " + userString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this would error, but we're not getting that far. It's the delete call that's causing the problem though. I've commented out the += to confirm without success.

Comment: Edited code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Can there be duplicates in the `users` collection? This might need to be checked to be sure, like user A is twice in the collection because it belongs to group foo and group bar

Comment: I've confirmed that the users collection only has a single user entered and still raises the exception.

Comment: does this happens at the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: Yes, First iteration of the loop and first user in the list.

Comment: Is your application running with elevated privileges?

Comment: Yes, the app runs with elevated privileges.